Flutter Web App does not render correctly on the mobile browsers
I have a Flutter web app that I am trying to host using Firebase hosting. On my first deployment, I identified that the app's look from the mobile and desktop browsers is very different. Reading some articles, it looks like a renderer issue.
I have tried deploying using the Canvaskit and HTML renderers, but the result is the same. Is there anything I need to configure for the run time, or any other suggestions?
Commands used for building:
flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit
flutter build web --release --web-renderer html
App looks smooth when loaded from desktop web browser
App looks different when loaded from mobile web browser
I am expecting the app to have a similar smooth look on the mobile web browser as well.

It would be helpful to post the code where you create your UI, perhaps there is an issue there that makes it scale in unwanted ways on various platforms/screen sizes
